# Is it possible to get a full compliance between Rhapsody generated IDL files and CORBA 3.1?

Tags: corba, idl, tao, rhapsody

I've tried to compile generated IDL files from Rhapsody 7.1.1 with the last version of TAO IDL Compiler (released package version 6.0.2), but I get some errors because anonymous types are deprecated in CORBA 3.1.

This kind of errors could be suppressed using TAO IDL Compiler "-as" option. But, for maintenance reasons, I want to generate compliant IDL files.

Also, I get other errors from the TAO IDL Compiler related with interface forwarding. This generated IDL files compile correctly until TAO version 5.7.9 (1.7.9).

Edited:

The main problem with interface forwarding is that a forward of an already defined interface hides the contents of such interface.

Example:

A.idl

```
interface A {

    typedef long my_long_type;
};
```

B.idl

```
#include "A.idl"

interface A;

interface B {
     typedef A::my_long_type my_b_long; // Error with TAO versions greater than 5.7.9
};
```

If I remove the forward of A there is no problem, but i can't because the IDL files are generated by Rhapsody by this way.

Comment: You may have a version problem with TAO.  Here is what I see:
Rhapsody 7.0 requires the ACE-5.5 and TAO-1.5 versions 
in http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rsdp/v1r0m0/topic/com.ibm.help.download.rhapsody.doc/pdf/corba.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the interface forward, create a small reproducer and if this is a bug in TAO_IDL, than report it in the TAO bugzilla at http://bugzilla.dre.vanderbilt.edu/

Comment: I've edited the question explaining the problem with forwardings. It doesn't seem to be a bug, is it?

Comment: Ok. I did it and it was a bug.

Comment: Yes, read that, Jeff fixed it quickly and it will be part of the next TAO release.